# (list (list ....))

Tags: sbcl

```
(list '+ 3 5)
```

(+ 3 5)

```
(list (+ 3 5))
```

(8)

```
(list (list '+ 3 5))
```

((+ 3 5))

Why the result of the third line is different of the result of the second line ?

Comment: because it's different code...?

Comment: Please edit your question and change it to a meaningful title!

Answer (score 2):

In the second example, `(+ 3 5)`, the numbers 3 and 5 are evaluated, and then the whole expression is evaluated by applying the function which corresponds to the symbol `+`, to the numbers 3 and 5.  (Numbers evaluate to themselves. That's why you don't need to add `'` to them in the first example.)

In the first example, Lisp evaluates `'+` (which results in the symbol `+`) as well as 3 and 5, and then applies the function `list` to them, which does nothing more than creating a list of its (evaluated) arguments.

The third example does the same thing to the inner list: The whole thing is evaluated, just as in the first example.  This results in `(+ 3 5)`.  Then the outer instance of the function `list` is applied to this result, wrapping another list around it.

Instead of the third example, maybe you wanted this:

```
(list (funcall #'+ 3 5))
```

In this case, `#'` tells Lisp to go and get the function associated with `+`.  Common Lisp normally stores functions in a different way than it stores the regular values of symbols.  Whereas the normal evaluation of a symbol gets the regular symbol value, evaluating `#'your-symbol` gets the associated function, if it exists.

Then `funcall` applies the function that was gotten with `#'+` to 3 and 5.  Then the value of that operation is passed to `list`, to produce `(8)`.

(There are more precise ways to say some of this, but I'm trying to get the ideas across to beginners.)

Answer (score 0):

LIST is a function which creates a list from it's arguments.
When an s-expression is evaluated Lisp checks first element of it and if it is a function (LIST is a function) it first iterates over every element in the list, evaluates them and passes values to the function as arguments.

In the second line you have inner form (i.e. (+ 3 5)) evaluated to 8 and outer (list ) call creates a list containing 1 element.

In the third line you have inner call to list evaulated to 3-element list (+ 3 5) as a value. It is not a form lisp will evaluate further, you just created list which has symbol + as a head. Evaluating outer list call will give another 1-element list (which contains 3-element list as head).

Hope it helps.